# Clip through blocks for a brief moment in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In spectator mode, a person is able to fly and clip through blocks, but is also invisible.

Is it possible to put a person in spectator mode temporarily? That is, is there a command/effect that a person in, say, adventure mode can use to switch to spectator mode for x ticks/seconds, then switch back to adventure mode?

Comment: Why not use just 2 command blocks?

Comment: @Crafter What, hook them up on Chain with enough repeaters between them to hold spectator mode as long as necessary? That just might work. I could then trigger the first with the methods described [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/311425/188871). Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: Well I am not an exact expert in redstone and it doesn't address the question of *how* to do it in 1 command block but nonetheless I shall post it as an answer in case no one else can provide a better solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You could always have 2 command blocks, one set to put them into spectator mode, and another to put them back into adventure mode.

Answer (score -1):

Sethbling made a video about a contraption that puts Creative players in Spectator mode when they get near a solid block. I don't know when you want your Adventure mode players to go into Spectator mode, but you could use something similar.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for. I was hoping to just click with an item and switch modes, regardless of my surroundings.

Comment: Apparently someone already archived this video: http://web.archive.org/web/20150426190956/https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WrJs8l7Es4s