# Is it possible to use an item to activate a command in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible to detect when a player right-clicks with a stick and activate a command?

What I'm trying to do is have several items with specific NBT data and set it so that right-clicking with those items uses certain commands (for instance, right-clicking with a specific sword will /summon a fireball, or right-clicking with a specific stick will activate a speed /effect). Is there a way to do this in vanilla Minecraft?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I apply an effect when a player left-clicks/right-clicks with an item in hand?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/226476/how-can-i-apply-an-effect-when-a-player-left-clicks-right-clicks-with-an-item-in)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dly's answer is fine, but DonielF is right. If you have a mob in you you can't hit anything.

In Minecraft you can't right click and trigger a command with all items. But some items (like carrot on a stick) can be used.

Example:

```
Type this in chat:

/scoreboard objectives add speed stat.useItem.minecraft.carrot_on_a_stick speed
/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar speed


Run this on a 1 tick clock:
    /effect @p[score_speed_min=1,score_speed=1] minecraft:speed 30 1
```

This will detect whenever a player right-clicks with a carrot on a stick and it will give him the effect speed 1 for 30 seconds.

It will also work with an empty map (make sure to remove the new map and give the player another empty map!) or when a placed cake is eaten.

Comment: Side note: With the introduction of the `using_item` advancement trigger, this got much simpler and can be used with a lot more items.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but not easy.

I know of two ways to do this:

**1. Villager + scoreboard objective:**

```
/scoreboard objectives add rightclicked stat.talkedToVillager
/summon Villager ~ ~ ~ {NoAI:1,Invulnerable:1,Silent:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Amplifier:1,Duration:9999,Ambient:0}],CustomName:"somespecialguy",Offers:{}}
```

make it "follow" the player: `/tp @e[type=Villager,name=somespecialguy] @a`

Now you can use the objective `rightclicked` to execute your command(s).

**2. Armor stand**

- Use an item which can be put into the hands of an armor stand
- Have an (invisible) armor stand constantly teleported to you
- whenever you right click your tool it will be put into the hand of that armor stand
- test for the armor stand holding that tool and give another item to you + execute your command(s)

Comment: But wouldn't left-clicking then attack the villager/armor stand rather than whatever I'm trying to attack?